# How to do the equivalent of Wolfram Language's ListPlot in WolframAlpha?

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica, wolframalpha, wolfram-language

The Wolfram Language defines the [`ListPlot` function](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html). However, it does not work in WolframAlpha except for some scenarios where it just gets interpreted as `plot ...`, but even then, it is interpreted as a single plot.

What I want to do is plot multiple (at least two) scatter plots made from lists of ordered pairs. So something like:

```js
ListPlot[{{{1,2}, {2,3}, {3,4}}, {{1,-1}, {2,-3}, {3,-2}}}]
```

which corresponds to the definition of:

```js
ListPlot[{data1,data2, ...}]
```

Whatever I have tried, including trying variations of `plot <list formatted various ways> and <other list>`, has not worked.

How do you plot multiple lists of ordered pairs in WolframAlpha on the same plot?